# How to do API Values in XElement

Tags: c#, xml

I need help with pass the value in the API to XElement in C#

Here the a piece of the API schema:

```
<xsd:element
name="EventStatus" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Event Status</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

Is this how that would be done?

```
new XElement("EventStatus", "Event Status"),
```

Comment: based on the given XSD you can put anything in EventStatus, at least anything that fits ax xsd:sting. So your example will qualify but so will `new XElement("EventStatus", "Foo Bar Baz"),`

Comment: so would something like this be better:          
     Saia.Data.General.Shipment prc = new Data.General.Shipment(); 
            new XElement("EventLocation",
            new XElement("Street1", prc.History),
            new XElement("City", prc.History),
            new XElement("StateProvince", prc.History),
            new XElement("PostalCode", prc.History),
            new XElement("CountryCode", prc.History),
            new XElement("EventStatus", prc.History)

Comment: Try : new XElement("EventStatus", new object[] { new XElement("A",x), new XElement("B",y)});